is it possible to add a link to MUI_LICENSEPAGE_TEXT_BOTTOM?
I am attempting to add a hyperlink to the bottom text of the license page.
For example:
!define MUI_LICENSEPAGE_TEXT_BOTTOM "Click this link -> http://www.google.com/"

!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_LICENSE "${license}"

I have looked around, and I have found there is a linker plugin for doing this sort of thing:
https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Linker_plug-in
This only seems to work for labels, though. Is it possible to do for the bottom text of the license page? I am also confused how the linker plugin works with FindWindow $0 "#32770" "" $HWNDPARENT how do we know the window number to use?

#32770 is dialog class: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/about-window-classes

NSIS does not have great support for links on non-custom pages.
You can use the Linker plug-in you found:
!include MUI2.nsh
!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_SHOW OnLicShow
!define MUI_LICENSEPAGE_TEXT_BOTTOM "Click this link -> http://www.google.com/"
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_LICENSE "${__FILE__}"
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE English

Function OnLicShow
!if ${MUI_SYSVERSION} >= 2
StrCpy $0 $mui.LicensePage.Text
!else
FindWindow $0 "#32770" "" $HWNDPARENT
GetDlgItem $0 $0 1006 ; <-- Use MakeNsisW.exe=>Tools=>Window Info to find this id
!endif
Linker::link /NOUNLOAD $0 "http://www.google.com/"
FunctionEnd

Or this crazy thing:
Unicode True
RequestExecutionLevel User
XPStyle On ; SysLink
PESubsysVer 5.1 ; SysLink is XP+
!include MUI2.nsh
!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_SHOW OnLicShow
!define MUI_LICENSEPAGE_TEXT_BOTTOM "Hello, click <A>this</A> if you dare"
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_LICENSE "${__FILE__}"
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE English #*/

Function OnLicShow
!if ${MUI_SYSVERSION} >= 2
StrCpy $0 $mui.LicensePage.Text
!else
FindWindow $0 "#32770" "" $HWNDPARENT
GetDlgItem $0 $0 1006 ; Use makensis.exe=>Tools=>Window Info to find this id
!endif
${NSD_GetText} $0 $1
${NSD_SetText} $0 ""
System::Call 'USER32::GetClientRect(pr0,@r2)'
System::Call '*$2(i,i,i.r3,i.r4)'
WndEvent::CreateWindow SysLink $1 ${WS_CHILD}|${WS_VISIBLE} 0 0 0 $3 $4 $0
Var /Global mysyslink
Pop $mysyslink
GetFunctionAddress $1 SysLinkHandler
WndEvent::AddHandler "NOTIFY" "$0" $1
FunctionEnd
!define /IfNDef NM_CLICK -2
!define /IfNDef NM_RETURN -4
Function SysLinkHandler
${If} $2 = ${NM_CLICK}
${OrIf} $2 = ${NM_RETURN}
    ${If} $mysyslink Z= $3
        ExecShell "" "http://example.com"
    ${EndIf}
${EndIf}
FunctionEnd

